# How to call another class's function from a class WITHOUT INHERITANCE

Tags: c++, class, object, member

so for one of the questions in our assignment, our prof gave us this following code snippet and asked us to make it run and implement it so that we are able to access class2's print() function from class1.

However, we are required to do this without the use of any inheritance/aggregation/composition between the two classes, which I am having trouble with. Aside from that, we are able to modify anything to make the code runnable. Thanks to anyone able to help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class class1 {
public:
    int x;
    class1()
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    void accessclass2(/* to be implemented*/)
    {
        //call the print() function from class2
    }
};

class class2 {
public:
    int y;
    class2()
    {
        y = 10;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << y << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{   //to be implemented; 
    //create class1 and class2 objects and access the print() function
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework question asking for the answer. No prior work is shown.

Answer (score 2):

If you separate these into .hpp and .cpp files, then you can forward declare `class2` and pass by pointer to `accessclass2`.

class1.hpp:

```
...
class class2;// forward declaration
...
class class1
{
    ...
    void accessclass2(class2 *x);
    ...
};
```

class1.cpp:

```
...
void class1::accessclass2(class2 *x)
{
    x->print();
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class class2 {
public:
    int y;
    class2()
    {
        y = 10;
    }
    void print() const
    {
        cout << y << endl;
    }
};

class class1 {
public:
    int x;
    class1()
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    void accessclass2(const class2 & cl2)
    {
        cl2.print();
    }
};

int main()
{   
    class2 c2 = class2();
    class1 c1 = class1();
    c1.accessclass2(c2);
    return 0;
}
```

more secure method would be to make print() as a constant function: **void print() const {}**

and passing c2 as const reference as 
   **void accessclass2(const class2 & cl2)**`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
int main()
{  
    //create class1 and class2 objects and access the print() function
    class2 c2Object;
    C2Object.print();

    // Oh, you want to use class2::print() from within class1? Ok:
    class1 c1Object;
    c1Object.accessclass2(&c2Object);
}

// In class2's implementation:
    void accessclass2(class2 *pClass2Object)
    {
        //call the print() function from class2
        pClass2Object->print();
    }
```